# Alarm Application Android

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am trying to make an alarm application, and found this code online. But when I copied it into eclipse, it gives an error on the startAlert method and says "void is an invalid type for the variable startAlert".

```
package tanvi.alarm;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        public void startAlert(View view) {
            EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            int i = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + (i * 1000), pendingIntent);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + i + " seconds",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the function under the `onCreate()` method, then call it inside the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: i put the function under onCreate() and that gave no error-simple one, my mistake did not see it...but how do i call it?

Comment: You call it like this, `startAlert(view);` the view is a variable that you have to pass to this function, if you don't need to pass a variable you would want to remove it, if you need to pass more variables you would want to put them as parameters, depends on what you want to do exactly!

Comment: if i want to pass a view, where do i create it?

Comment: just before (above it) you call `startAlarm()` inside `onCreate()` method like this: `View v = new View(this); startAlarm(v);`

Answer (score 1):

function `startAlert` should be out side of `onCreate`..

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          startAlert(view ); //<--------- no need to pass view if function is on same activity 
    }




    public void startAlert(View view) {
                EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                int i = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                        + (i * 1000), pendingIntent);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + i + " seconds",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

Comment: okay..i am new to this, but i ll be creating a broadcast receiver, and nowhere can i find the view being passed through the intent, so removing view will not be a problem for the alarm?